# How can I derive the big O notation?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm learning about big O notation and I need help trying to understand how the big O notation for the following program is derived:

```
static void myMethod(int[] arr, in t)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
  {
    int variable = nextMethod(inputArray, i, n - 1);
    int temp = inputArray[i];
    inputArray[i] = inputArray[variable];
    inputArray[variable] = temp;
  }
}

static int nextMethod(int[] inputArray, int first, int last)
{
  int maximum = inputArray[first];
  int indexOfMaximum = first;
  for (int index = last; index > first; index--)
  {
    if (inputArray[index] > maximum)
    {
      maximum = inputArray[index];
      indexOfMaximum = index;
    }
  }
  return indexOfMaximum;
}
```

The answer I have been given is:
2 (n-1) + 3(n*(n-1))/2 + 3(n -1)
= O(n) + O(n^2) + O(n)
= O(n^2). But I'm not sure how it is being derived... would appreciate any guidance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1)
In myMethod, the for-loop is rotated by n-1.

Step 2)
In the nextMethod function, the first goes from last to last, but in the worst case scenario, this will be n.

Therefore, it is done as much as (n-1)*n. (Programming Operations)

If you make this one axis, you will have a time complexity of n^2.

Summary:

just did Repeat 2 times.

It must be considered in the worst case by case.

If you have any questions, please leave comments.

Comment: Why would step 2 be considered n?

Comment: main, recursive function
Because you wrote these two functions.